# How to test with pytest a function or method returning a function?

Tags: python, pytest, tdd

I want to test my code and one of the most important function return a function.
I tried:

```py
import pytest
from operator methodcaller
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def foo(info: str):
    imshow = methodcaller("imshow", np.zeros(3,3))
    a = {'a': imshow}
    return a.get(info)

def test_foo():
    imshow = methodcaller("imshow", np.zeros(3,3))
    assert(foo('a') == imshow)
```

but this does not work because the 2 function aren't the same object.
Does a methodology exist for this kind of testing?

I use python3.8

Comment: Where does `f` come from? It's not defined in `foo`, so it must be available *outside* the call to `foo` in order to compare to `foo`'s return value. (Or, more likely, is `f` a typo for `imshow`?)

Comment: @chepner Yes it was a typo I rewrite this post twice sorry, I did the modification

Comment: The best you can do is verify that the returned function *behaves* as expected (to the extent that you can test it on various inputs). Determining if two functions are equivalent is undecidable.

Comment: So if I have understand correctly in that case I need to test the matplotlib function ```imshow``` right?